# how to return the result outside the if statement

Tags: c#-4.0, revit-api

I was writing a revit pluging using c#. I couldn't return the result without assign public variable.  Below is my code.I am not sure what is the error. Error in last codeline - return stid

public ElementId sysid(Duct elt, Document doc)

```
    {
        ElementId stid;
        FilteredElementCollector DuctSystemcollector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
        ICollection<Element> DuctSystem = DuctSystemcollector.OfClass(typeof(MechanicalSystemType)).ToElements();

        foreach (Element j in DuctSystem)
        {
            string sn = j.GetParameters("Type Name")[0].AsString();
            if (sn == elt.GetParameters("System Type")[0].AsValueString())
            {
                 stid = j.Id;
                //return stid;
                //TaskDialog.Show("Duct shape ", stid);
            }

        }
        return  stid;
    }
```

Comment: What this code is expected to do? What does it do instead? What's the issue you are facing? `I am not sure what is the error` We too are not sure..

Comment: I need to compare two parameters from a Revit element and if it matches, I need to return the variable stid.  Now the variable stid is getting red.

Comment: what is `ElementId`? if it is a class then you need to do `ElementId stid = null;`

Comment: ElementId stid = null; // correct answer.  Thank you